# it cames or it came?

Tags: grammar

*The dragonfly it ran away

But it came back with a story to say*

The song is nice, but it trouble**s** me.
Why is there no **s** at came?

Comment: Surely a dragonfly would _fly_ away?

Comment: @KateBunting Maybe, [but that's the song](https://greatsong.net/PAROLES-OF-MONSTERS-AND-MEN,DIRTY-PAWS,311338.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Came" is the past tense form of "come".  The past tense in Engish does not have a distinct third-person form, both for regular and irregular verbs.

I play / It plays
I played / It played

I come / It comes
I came / It came